# Turn tables from MySQL Database into variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a MySQL database which have simple tables like this:

```
colorTable
label | price | name
---------------------
red      10      Red
blue     20      Blue

sizeTable
label | price | name | available
---------------------------------
small    5       Small    Yes
med      10      Med      No
```

I want to load those variables into javascript variables so that they are an array of objects like this:

```
var colorTable = [
    {label:'red', price: '10', name: 'Red'},
    {label:'blue', price: '20', name: 'Blue'}
];

var sizeTable = [
     {label:'small', price: '5', name: '10', available: 'Yes'},
     {label:'med', price: '10', name: 'Med', available: 'No'}
];
```

I was able to load them in by outputting the variables into a plain `.php` file and loading that file as a javascript file, but something tells me there is a better way and I have no idea what that way would be?

I'm fine using plain javascript or jQuery, whichever is easiest.

It would need to loop through an unlimited number of tables (and columns within those tables) to automatically pull data for every table added to the database.

Comment: Why can't you `json_encode()` the array you're retrieving from your table?

Comment: Yep, like Blake says, just have a file where your php calls `echo json_encode(mySqlResults);` then call that file with ajax and process the results exactly like you want

Comment: In the question I mention that's what i'm already doing, but there has to be a better way than loading a PHP file as a javascript file.

Comment: @see the edit to my comment, hold on, ill post an example

Answer (score 1):

Have a `getData.php` page that gets your data from the database like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['command'])&&$_POST['command']=='getMyData'){ 
    // .... get data from db
    // in your php, you'll need to loop over the tables you have and order the results something like this:

    $tables=["colorTable"=> $colorTableQueryResult, "sizeTable"=>$sizeTableQueryResult];
    echo json_encode($tables);
    exit;
}
```

Then in a .js file, have this:

```
       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "getData.php",
          data: {command:'getMyData'},
          dataType:'JSON',
          success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);             
          },
          error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            console.log(err.Message);
          }
       });
```

The result should be:

```
   {
    colorTable = [{
        label: 'red',
        price: '10',
        name: 'Red'
      }, {
        label: 'blue',
        price: '20',
        name: 'Blue'
      }],
      sizeTable: [{
          label: 'small',
          price: '5',
          name: '10',
          available: 'Yes'
        }, {
          label: 'med',
          price: '10',
          name: 'Med',
          available: 'No'
        }
      }
```

Access them like `response.colorTable`

Comment: I can't manually be adding in tables like that, it has to auto detect which tables are in the database and automatically assign the variables.

Comment: See my edit, just setup the array in your php then use the response object however you want, all the data will be there.